# Reading two Files and comparing in C++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to compare the user input to a file, I was able to open it. let me just show it

```
cout<< "Please Enter your Student ID:  ";
 cin >> stdID;
 cout<< "Please Enter your Course ID:  ";
 cin >> courseID;

 if the courseID is similar to the prerequisite file, eligible, if not, not eligible..
    this is the file     
    course Prereq
    cs111 NA
    cs112 cs111
    cs240 cs112
    cs241 cs240
    cs214 cs112
    cs215 cs112
    cs218 cs111
    cs310 cs215
    cs311 cs112
    cs317 cs215
    cs318 cs218
    cs324 cs240
    cs341 cs241
```

Comment: You are not comparing files but user input.

Comment: sorry, just corrected it

Comment: Let me get this straight, you read a course id from the user, then you want to check one of the fields in the file you show? The first field or the second field (not that it really matters)? What have you tried? Do you know how to read input from a file? Do you know how to compare strings? Can you please be more specific about what problem you have?

Comment: yes...the second row...I have opened the file but only left with comparing the user input to the file...

Comment: example, if courseID is cs240...it should print out "not eligible, do cs112"

Comment: its okay guys, iv got the answer. thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

For something simple like this, I would read the input in a simple `while` loop, using the input operator `>>` to read into two strings (and relying on the fact that the `operator>>` function returns the stream, and that streams can be used in boolean conditions).

Then in the loop compare the user-input with the first string, and if it's a match then output the second string (if it's not e.g. `"NA"`).